# I want to write a variable out but delete the top 3 lines

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script to check all of the online computers and then make it one neat column Here is the code I have so far...

```
$computers = get-adcomputer -LDAPFilter "(Name=SDA000*)" | Select-Object -Property Name 

$computers1 =  get-adcomputer -LDAPFilter "(Name=SDA005*)" | Select-Object -Property Name 

$computers2 =  get-adcomputer -LDAPFilter "(Name=SDA006*)" | Select-Object -Property Name 

$computers3 =  get-adcomputer -LDAPFilter "(Name=SDA007*)" | Select-Object -Property Name 

$computers4 = ($computers) + ($computers1) + ($computers2) + ($computers3)

[array]$online = @($computers4.Name | % {test-connection -erroraction silentlycontinue -Count 1 $_}) 

$wIw = $online | Select-Object Address

$wIw
```

But the output always leaves the top 3 lines with extraneous data I don't want. i.e

```
Address
-------
SDA0003
SDA0007
SDA000B
SDA000C
SDA0050
SDA0051
SDA0054
SDA0057
SDA005F
SDA0061
SDA006B
SDA006D
SDA0076
```

I can write it to a text file and then pipe it to `select-object -skip 3`, but that does not seem to work with a variable.

thanks for any advice.

Comment: I assume by extraneous data you mean the property name (`Address`). If so you can get the property values using member access enumeration on your result: `$online.Address`

Comment: Hi there! Not directly related to your question but I do that kind of things at times and it would be a nice enhancement for your script to parallelize your test-connection calls. It would make it much faster if you have a lot of machines :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the header (e.g. the "Address" property). To output it to the screen without the header, you can use the `-HideTableHeaders` in a `Format-Table` command:

```
...
$wIw = $online | Select-Object Address

$wIw | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh yes, that treat is sometimes quit helpful but most of the time it is in the way. Here is how I get rid of it:

```
$computers = (get-adcomputer -LDAPFilter "(Name=SDA000*)" | Select-Object -Property Name).name
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want can be done easier like this:

```
$wIw = (Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(Name=SDA00*)" | 
        Where-Object { ($_.Name | Test-Connection -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) }).Name
```